# Knockout - How to reset Dynamic observable array with new value

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, lazy-loading, observablecollection

I can't reset observable array with new value am using some lazy loading Technic.
I can clear but can't reset, but it not allowing me to add new dynamic value.

**fiddle**
http://jsfiddle.net/kspxa8as/

**js**

```
var i = 1;
            optionsProvider = function(self) {
                var self = self || {};
                self.options = {};
                self.get = function(name, initialValue) {
                    if (!self.options[name]) {
                        console.log("Called - " + name);
                        self.options[name] = ko.observableArray([initialValue]);
                        var requestHeader = '';
                        setTimeout(function() {
                            var aa = [{name: "plant 1" + i, selected: true}, {name: "palnt 2" + i, selected: false}];
                            self.options[name](aa);
                            i++;
                        }, 2000);
                    }
                    return self.options[name];
                };
                return self;
            };
            ViewModel = function() {
                var self = this;
                var k = 1;
                var ob = new optionsProvider(self);
                self.PlantSelected = ob.get("name" + k, '');
                self.fillNewSelect = function() {
                    self.PlantSelected.removeAll();
                    self.PlantSelected().push(ob.get("name" + k, ''));
                    k++;
                };
            };
            ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

**HTML**

```
<select class="n_imported_country"                     
            data-bind="options: PlantSelected,
                               optionsText :'name'   
            "
            >
    </select>
    <div data-bind="click: function(){
         $root.fillNewSelect();
    }">click to fill new select value</div>
```

I am a newbie to knockout, great welcome your answers.

Comment: use `self.PlantSelected.push(ob.get("name" + k, ''));` instead `()` . `()` used to read where as if you need to add some data to it you need to use the declared instace i.e `sel.PlantSelected=ko.observableArray()` cheers

Comment: not working it just print c in dropdown. i dont know y

Comment: please try the posted answer that should fix the issue .

Comment: @supercool thats will not work since our dropdown set via ajax call. so it wil have some delay. use with set timeout fucntion. that will not work

Comment: timeour for ajax call,where i wil add my ajax call.so dynamically set value

Comment: @supercool asny update..?

Comment: gimme a sec let me check .

Comment: just try this http://jsfiddle.net/supercool/kspxa8as/5/ . all process will be async this is better way making things .

Comment: i think you put ajax call inside viewmodel, actually that get function is for fetch options from ajax,so please put settimeout inside the get and please have a try.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79640/discussion-between-muhammed-uvais-and-super-cool).

Comment: @supercool please see caht, http://jsfiddle.net/kspxa8as/, i wil replace the settimeout with ajax call in the above fiddle.

Comment: updated my answer(ajax call way) which should work in all cases irrespective . cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this the *trick* here is passing the instance of the observableArray to the function and get our job done

**Viewmodel:**

```
 var  ViewModel = function() {
        var self = this;
        var k = 1;
        var ob = new optionsProvider(self);
        self.PlantSelected = ko.observableArray(); //Declare it as observableArray
        ob.get("name" + k, '',self.PlantSelected) // call the function passing observableArray instance 
        self.fillNewSelect = function() 
        {
          self.PlantSelected.removeAll();
          ob.get("name", ''+ k,self.PlantSelected)
           k++;
        };
  };
 ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

**function :**

```
  var i = 1;
  optionsProvider = function(self) {
      var self = self || {};
        self.options = {};
          self.get = function(name, initialValue,instance) { //pass observableArray instance here
          if (!self.options[name] || self.options[name]()) {
            var requestHeader = '';

            setTimeout(function() {
            var aa = [{name: "plant 1" + i, selected: true}, 
                      {name: "palnt 2" + i, selected: false}];
                   instance(aa); // assign data to instance 
             },2000);
          i++;
       }
    return true;      
   };
  return self;
};
```

working sample **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/supercool/kspxa8as/7/)**

Comment: this will not work,since i have a ajax call inside get function. setTimeout(function() {
                                self.options[name](aa);
                                 }, 2000);   please check with setTime out function.

Comment: updated fiddle  [http://jsfiddle.net/kspxa8as/4/](http://jsfiddle.net/kspxa8as/4/)

Comment: Alex Filatov, the dropdown called many times many section in one application. so i have used lazy loading Technic

Answer (score 1):

I recommend the use of a promise library to handle the asynchronous Ajax load of new items. I've used jQuery's implementation in the sample below. Notice how `optionsProvider` no longer requires any dependency on the viewmodel.

```
var optionsProvider = function (name, initialValue) {
    return function () {
        return $.get("/target/url", {parameter: "value"})
        .fail(function () {
            console.log("request to get new items failed", arguments);
        });
    };
};

var ViewModel = function () {
    var self = this,
        k = 1,
        ob = optionsProvider("name" + k, '');

    self.PlantSelected = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.fillNewSelect = function () {
        ob().then(function (newData) {
            var p = self.PlantSelected;
            p.removeAll();
            p.push.apply(p, newData);
        });
    };

    // init
    self.fillNewSelect();
};
ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

The second change to mention is the way to push new objects into an array. `.push()` supports an argument list:

```
arr.push('a', 'b', 'c')
```

If you have an array of items you want to push (for example a JSON result), you would use `.apply()`, otherwise you would push the array *itself* as the first item:

```
arr.push.apply(arr, ['a', 'b', 'c']);
```

Observable arrays in knockout support the same usage.

Compare: http://jsfiddle.net/kspxa8as/6/